# Removing index.php with add-on domain - CP urls break

Tags: control-panel, url, htaccess, subdomain, rewrite

I have EE Core installed in a subdirectory of my site, but it is set up as an add-on domain.

I followed the official instructions to remove index.php and the urls work if I type them manually (without index.php), but all the links generated from the CP break:

View Site link displays like this:
http://domain.me/?URL=http://domain.me/

View Template displays:
http://domain.me/?URL=http://domain.me/services and doesn't rewrite.

However, if I type in domain.me/services, the rewrite works. I can see that it's stripping the "services" segment, but I don't know why.

This is the only thing in my .htaccess:

```
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these lines at the end of your .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(ACT=.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(URL=.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(CSS=.*)$ [NC]   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php\?&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Could you explain exactly what those additional rules are doing? Thank you so much.

Comment: In short, adding question mark after index.php to process these special URL requests. 
If the answer has helped you, please mark it as correct.